# How do I identify the error row when using batch insert (INSERT INTO table2 SELECT * FROM table1)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I use the following SQL statement to batch insert large amount of data into another table, for example:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (col1, col2) 
    SELECT col1, col2 
    FROM table1 
    WHERE condition and some logics ...;
```

Normally, roughly 5000 rows are inserted into table2.

However, if 2 rows are invalid in a batch, and they causes some an error when inserting data.

SQL Server raises an error and stops (or rollback) the statement.

And therefore, no row are inserted into table2 because of an error.

My questions are:

1. How do I insert all valid data as much as possible into a target table if an error occurs in a batch insertion ?
2. In addition, how do I identify the rows which cause errors after SQL Server raises errors ?

I searched the Internet for any possible solution, but I can't find any hit about it.

Comment: Post the table definition it most likely has to do with the type, lenght or constraints of the colums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In transactional database management system, constraints are made to maintain data integrity and can be extremely various depending on the table schema and how you wrote them.

`INSERT` is a standard SQL operation that allows you to put information into your database according to your schema. Hence, to answer your questions:

> 1. How do I insert all valid data as much as possible into a target table if an error occurs in a batch insertion ?

With `INSERT`, there is no way you can achieve it directly in your operation as the constraints can be broadly scoped. But there is `MAXERRORS` argument that comes with `BULK INSERT` command allowing you to let valid data through when inserting records before it hit the error threshold and stop the operation.

The only way you can achieve it using `INSERT` command is by specifying `WHERE` clause to your `INSERT ... SELECT ...` command according to the destination table's constraints.

> 2. In addition, how do I identify the rows which cause errors after SQL server raises errors ?

Unfortunately SQL Server does not specifically point out the row since in most, or may be all RDBMS, `INSERT` is plain record insertion command. There is another argument in `BULK INSERT` command named `ERRORFILE` that you can use to check failed row and the reason behind.

Read a complete `BULK INSERT` reference [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms188365.aspx).

To sum it up, `INSERT` is not the most sophisticated know-it-all command there is for inserting data into SQL database. This function should be handled in your application side rather than database side.

However, there is `BULK INSERT` command that can take you there from a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

Here if you want to insert all valid data then you need to add where condition and filter out invalid data like below

INSERT INTO table2 (col1, col2) 
SELECT col1, col2 FROM table1 WHERE **col1 IS NOT NULL AND  col12 IS NOT NULL**

We may add other condition which will cause issue in Insert, also same way we will also able to know the invalid data, just reverse the where condition as below:

SELECT col1, col2 FROM table1 WHERE **col1 IS NULL AND col12 IS NULL**